# How to modify an existing configuration file such as .ssh/config inside the container on ddev

Tags: ddev

I need this to simplify my drush alias configuration, so I can establish servers, jumpboxes and usernames/keys in the config file and keep everything else simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**  These days this operation is much easier, see https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/in-container-configuration/

To change the `/home/.ssh/config`, you just need to add a `.ssh/config` file in the `.ddev/homeaditions` folder and make sure to include the following lines:

```
UserKnownHostsFile=/home/.ssh-agent/known_hosts
StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

**-- The following is only valid for ddev < 1.10 --**

This is the solution I've implemented:

Because I didn't want to handle multiline additions, I decided to add a config file that would be appended to the `/home/.ssh/config` file.

I added a custom docker compose file in the .ddev folder: `docker-compose.volumes.yml`:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  web:
    volumes:
      - "./config:/etc/custom-config"
```

Then created the config folder inside the .ddev folder and added a configuration file with the content I wanted: `extra-config.txt`

Then, simply added a post-start hook in the `config.yml` file as @rfay suggested:

```
hooks:
  post-start:
    - exec: bash -c 'cat /etc/custom-config/extra-config.txt >> /home/.ssh/config'
```

Watch out because the commands need to be wrapped on `bash -c`, otherwise it would just output stdout and not modify the file.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this!  It might be easier to put extra-config.txt in your project and just copy it from there, then you wouldn't need the extra docker-compose.volumes.yaml.

Comment: True, but it is a project where not everybody uses ddev and each dev have their own local envs :)